# Distribution of i.i.d. random variables $X$ and $Y$ if $XY \sim \text{Beta}(\alpha, \beta)$

Tags: random-variable, beta-distribution, transform, deconvolution

This is a follow-up to the question [Square root of a Beta(1,1) random variable](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/522201/square-root-of-a-beta1-1-random-variable), which received two great answers.

If $XY \sim \text{Beta}(\alpha, \beta)$, and $X$ and $Y$ are two independent identically distributed random variables, do we know their distribution? If there is no simple general solution, can we figure out the distribution of $X$ and $Y$ for the case $XY \sim \text{Beta}(1, 1)$?

From my search so far I guess this is a deconvolution problem for which no readily worked-out solution, such as the Kumaraswamy distribution in the previous question, exists. However, I would appreciate to be proven wrong in this regard.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In the case of $Z=XY\sim \text{Beta}(\alpha,1)$, the moment generating function (mgf) of $-\ln(XY)=-\ln X-\ln Y$ is
\begin{align}
M_{-\ln(XY)}(t) 
   &= E(e^{-t\ln Z})
\\ &=E(Z^{-t})
\\ &=\int_0^1 z^{-t}\alpha z^{\alpha-1}dz
\\ &= \frac{1}{1-t/\alpha}
\end{align}
which is the mgf of an exponentially distributed random variable with rate parameter $\alpha$.

Thus, if $X$ and $Y$ are iid, this means that $-\ln X$ and $-\ln Y$ must be Gamma distributed with shape parameter $1/2$ and rate parameter $\alpha$ (see [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_distribution#Summation)).
Backtransforming, the pdf of $X$ and $Y$ is
$$
f(x)=\sqrt{-\frac\alpha{\pi\ln x}}x^{\alpha-1}
$$
for $0\le x\le 1$.

A similar calculation in the general Beta$(\alpha,\beta)$-case leads to
$$
M_{-\ln(XY)}(t)=\frac{\Gamma(\alpha-t)\Gamma(\alpha+\beta)}{\Gamma(\alpha+\beta-t)\Gamma(\alpha)}
$$
and the mgf of $-\ln X$ and $-\ln Y$ would need to be the square root of this.  But that is not the mgf of any known distribution and such a distribution (that when convolved with itself produces the target density) may not even exist.

The pdf of $-\ln X$ can be computed via numerical integration of the [inversion formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_function_(probability_theory)#Inversion_formulae) for the characteristic function $\varphi(t)=(M_{-\ln(XY}(it))^{1/2}$.  This seems to produce valid pdfs for $\beta\le 2$ but for $\beta > 2$, the resulting function no longer appear to be a valid pdf:

[image]

R code:

```
library(pracma)
f <- function(x,phi,...) {
  integrand <- function(t) {
    exp(-1i*t*x)*phi(t,...)
  }
  line_integral(integrand,c(-300+0i,300+0i))/(2*pi)
}
f <- Vectorize(f,vectorize.args = "x")
phi <- function(t, alpha, beta) {
  sqrt(gammaz(alpha - 1i*t)*gammaz(alpha + beta)/(gammaz(alpha + beta - 1i*t)*gamma(alpha)))
}
x <- seq(-1,3,by=.01)
fx <- f(x, phi, alpha=3,beta=2.5)
plot(x,Re(fx),type="l")
```

Comment: This looks extremely useful. Can you maybe add a hint, how you derived the relationships in the first paragraph? Or how they are called?

Comment: @LuckyPal I added some more explanation and made the result slightly more general.

Comment: *"but for β>2, the resulting function no longer appear to be a valid pdf"* Is it not valid because of the negative values? But, those negative values only appear outside of the support $0<x<1$.